# How to solve a Haskell exercise about IO

Tags: haskell, io, abstraction

I have been learning Haskell for few months on my own now by doing some exercises I found on some lecturers site, and I stumbled upon this one and cannot figure how to solve it.

There are two tasks that are kinda "connected". I solved the first one with ease, but don't really understand how to do the other one.

Here's the first one:

> Exercise 2. (Recall IO programming in Haskell and the do notation)
>
> Write a recursive function
>
> ```
> sumInts :: Integer -> IO Integer
> ```
>
> that repeatedly reads integer numbers from IO until the number 0 is given.
>   At that point, the function should return the sum of all the entered numbers
>   plus the original (default) value, which is given as a function parameter.

I solved this one this way:

```
getInt :: IO Integer          
getInt = do  
  s <- getLine
  return (read s)


sumInts :: Integer -> IO Integer
sumInts input = do
  x<-getInt
  if x==0 then return input else (x+) <$> sumInts input
```

It was pretty easy to do. Here's the other one, the one I cannot understand:

> Exercise 3. Generalize the previous IO interaction into a higher order
>   function
>
> ```
> whileIO :: IO a -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a -> a) -> a -> IO a
> ```
>
> which, for the given reading IO action, termination condition, folding function,
>   and the original value, returns the required IO action. Check that for
>   some values of getIO, condF, foldF, we can redefine sumInts as
>
> ```
> sumInts = whileIO getIO condF foldF
> ```

Would love some help with this one. :)

Comment: instead of `(x+) <$> sumInts input`, you could just do `sumInts (x+input)`. --- "folding" means "accumulating" btw.

Comment: Or you could drop the `input` argument entirely, replacing the base case with 0 instead, and write `(x+) <$> sumInts` in the recursive case. Of course since the problem specification requires you to accept an input, you would have to do my suggestion in a `go` auxiliary function or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

try to generalize your code, making pieces of it as parameters instead of hardcoding them. For instance, replace the `getInt` with a more general `getIO` parameter.

```
sumInts :: IO Integer -> Integer -> IO Integer
sumInts getIO input = do
    --  ^^^^^
  x<-getIO -- <------
  if x==0 then return input else (x+) <$> sumInts input
```

Then replace `x==0` with a generic predicate.

Then replace `(x+)` using a generic folding function.

And so on.

At the very end you'll get the wanted `whileIO`, and you can also give it the more general type suggested by the exercise.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try it out now. I still wont mark it as answered yet, while I'm not over with it! Thanks chi.